# How do I move a sprite by clicking other sprites in the stage?

Tags: libgdx, sprites

I am new to the LibGDX environment; how do I move a sprite by clicking other sprites in the stage?

[image: I want to move a ball left and right by clicking on arrow keys, at the bottom left and right of the screen.]

As you can see, I have an object I wish to move by clicking on arrow keys. Here are my current scripts:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        ScreenViewport viewport = new ScreenViewport();

        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Myactor actor = new Myactor();
        stage.addActor(actor);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.33f,0.66f,0.99f,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () { }
}

public class Myactor extends Actor {

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball.png"));
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    Texture Tsol = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left.png"));
    Sprite Ssol = new Sprite(Tsol);

    Texture Tsag = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right.png"));
    Sprite Ssag = new Sprite(Tsag);

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() 
                - sprite.getWidth() - 50, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
        sprite.draw(batch);

        Ssol.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - sprite.getWidth(), 0);
        Ssol.setRotation(90f);
        Ssol.draw(batch);

        Ssag.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()
                - sprite.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-sprite.getHeight());
        Ssag.setRotation(90f);
        Ssag.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible, I would recommend using the Scene2d that's included with libgdx. For your left and right arrows, turn them into ImageButtons and add a Touch listener or InputListener, I forget what it's called.

If you want to stick with your sprites, you may be able to do the same thing. If you have a bounding box around the Sprite, you can check if your input is inside the box, and if so, do movement.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a bounding box Check for the control sprites on TouchDown and move accordingly.

example:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    float x = Gdx.input.getX();
    float y = Gdx.input.getY();
    if(Ssag.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x,y)){
        //move sprite some amount
    }
    if(Ssol.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x,y)){
        //move sprite some other amount
    }
}
```

like Joey Mentioned though you can achieve the same thing with more functionality if you use the built in libgdx scene2d api. Good luck, Hope it helped !